# How can I reshape the dataframe so there is only 1 observation for each id?

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I need to reshape (I assume it's some sort of reshape like I would do in stata) this dataframe so that there is only 1 observation for each id. In addition, I need to preserve all of the other variables. So, one row should have columns for id, each year which contains the value of var1, x, var2 (var2 is not absolutely necessary. I've tried a lot of different things and I keep getting the same long data for the id variables. I apologize for the long dput() but there would not be information if I only did the first 6 rows.

```
  structure(list(id= c(1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 
        1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 
        1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 1806968L, 2022610L, 2022610L, 2022610L, 
        2022610L, 2022610L), var1 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 4877, 5819, 6560, 8262, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), x = c(25518, 
        25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 
        25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 25518, 34611, 34611, 34611, 34611, 
        34611), var2 = c(200812L, 200912L, 201012L, 201112L, 201212L, 
        201312L, 201512L, 201612L, 201712L, 201812L, 201912L, 200612L, 
        200512L, 200712L, 201412L, 199612L, 199712L, 199812L, 199912L, 
        200012L), `1987` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1988` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1989` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1990` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1991` = c(0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1992` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1993` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1994` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1995` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1996` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1997` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1998` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `1999` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2000` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2001` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2002` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2003` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2004` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2005` = c(0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5819, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            `2006` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4877, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2007` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 6560, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2008` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2009` = c(0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            `2010` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0), `2011` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2012` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2013` = c(0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            `2014` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8262, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2015` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2016` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2017` = c(0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
            `2018` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0), `2019` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `2020` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
        -20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x55b410de6890>, sorted = c("id", 
        "var1", "x", "var2"))
```

I would like it to look something like this, for which the value in each year is the value of var1 that corresponds with that year. Here is a something of what I want without all the years. I still need a column for all years.

```
id <- c(1806968L, 2022610L)
"1987" <- c(0, 8262)
x <- c(25518, 34611)
data <- data.frame(id, `1987`, x)
```

Comment: `tidyr::pivot_longer()` is what you want

Comment: Can you show a small example of what you want your output to look like? Your description is complex.

Comment: @dash2 I just edited with something similar to what I'm look for, but with only 1 year instead of all years.

Comment: Still confused. Why in your example is `x1987` equal to 8262 for id 2022610?

Comment: @dash2, because the value of var1 would fill into x1987. In the larger dataset, The value for var1 for id 20022610 is 8262.

Comment: Right. So the value of var1 for id 2022610 is 8262. Why does it fill into x1987,  rather than, say, 1988?

Comment: @dash2 You're right. The value of the years is already filled with correct value. I just need to collapse the id value into 1 row. Let me see if I can run  your code below.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear whether you also want years which are 0 when x is 0. If you do, delete `& var1 > 0` below.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
tmp %>%
      tidyr::pivot_longer(c(starts_with("1"), starts_with("2")), names_to = "year") %>%
      filter(value == var1 & var1 > 0) %>% 
      select(-value)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting: 
Error: 'pivot_longer' is not an exported object from 'namespace:tidyr'